# Facebook share wrong information crawl og:url og:image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I am trying to share my web page on facebook. However, it just shows wrong url,image and all other data crawled seems to be incorrect .

This is what I have as per testing :

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/19/arts/international/when-great-minds-dont-think-alike.html" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="When Great Minds Don’t Think Alike" />
<meta property="og:description" content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
```

But it shows wrong data and none of the information from above tags is grabbed when sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook caches the OpenGraph data -- the data stored in your og tags. To reset the cached data, you can go to this page and ask Facebook to scrape your website again:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to press the scrape button to refresh the cache in Facebook. otherwise it won't refresh itself regularly. [Facebook debugger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARy2y.png)

You can also try this simple web app to share with a custom image you want: http://come.toTheTerminal.com